# pytest.mark.parameterize not "finding" fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing tests for a small library and I decided to use py.test after hearing so many good things about it.

However, `pytest.mark.parameterize` is giving me some issues. At first, I thought maybe I just mismatched some parens and it went off looking for a fixture elsewhere. So I decided to start with the given example of parameterize:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])
def test_eval(input, expected):
    assert eval(input) == expected
```

But this gives the same error:

> fixture 'input' not found
>
> available fixtures: capfd, pytestconfig, recwarn, capsys, tmpdir, monkeypatch
>
> use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

I went off googling, but I couldn't find any answers that applied. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Edit: I suppose knowing which Python/py.test versions is helpful.

Python 3.4.0 and py.test 2.6.4

Comment: Which python and py.test version are you using? Your code works for me.

Comment: I suppose that would be helpful. Python 3.4 and py.test 2.6.4, I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: Exactly the same as me (well, python 3.4.2). Have you tried reinstalling py.test, as there might be something weird in the setup? Does running that code in isolation show the error, or is there any other code / environment vars / config files needed?

Comment: I tried reinstalling, but the issue persists. :/ There shouldn't be additional configuration or setup required. I am running it in isolation using virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper. I raised an issue in the bug tracker for py.test to see if the maintainers can shed some light.

Comment: @matsjoyce Turns out I'm not a very good speller and it's `parametrize` rather than `parameterize`. I copy-pasted the code into the SO form, but wrote it by hand in my script, which explains why it runs for you and not for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just tried your example verbatim and it worked fine in pytest 2.6.4. Perhaps you are misspelling `parametrize`? You misspelled it in the title and is a common mistake, as can be seen in [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/463).

Comment: And that was the issue. I wish this had been the first a time a small oversight has confused me for hours, but sadly it's not. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, it's common mistake.

Answer (score 9):

It's not the same cause, but this is the first result on google for "pytest parametrize fixture not found", which was my natural google for the same error as OP:

> E fixture 'blah' not found

In my case it was due to a silly typo (which I didn't spot for far too long!), missing the @ from the decorator:

```
pytest.mark.parametrize("blah", [50, 100])
def test_something(blah):
    assert blah > 0
```

Comment: I have no idea why someone chose to mark your answer down, but this 25-year Python user thanks you for bothering to report exactly the mistake I was making!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed a dataclass to `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

I forgot `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is a decorator.
As a result, I didn't put the decorator above the function, and between the decorator and the function, there were other functions.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])

def test_otherfunctions():
    """ a function unrelated to the decorator. """
    pass

#the decorator should be here.
def test_eval(input, expected):
    assert eval(input) == expected
```

In my case, a fix is just a reorder.

```py
def test_otherfunctions():
    """ a function unrelated to the decorator. """
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])
def test_eval(input, expected):
    assert eval(input) == expected
```